# Move (mv) files with crontab

Tags: cron

I'm currently using this to delete files from a specific folder.

```
25 * * * * /bin/rm -rf /var/www/website/current/integration/export/*
```

I want it to continue to be at the same time as well but instead of deleting them i want to migrate them to the `export_completed` folder. So should i just use the syntax below and that's it?

```
25 * * * * mv /var/www/website/current/integration/export/* /var/www/website/current/integration/export_completed/
```

Comment: Yes. Do you see any error ?

Comment: I do not and it works correctly. Thank you for reassuring me. =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is correct.

May want to use /bin/mv if mv doesnt work.

Also the directories must exist.

Comment: What's the behavior in the different syntax?

Comment: Does the exact same thing. It just that u have used `/bin/rm` which you know seems to work. im just suggesting if mv doesnt work than `/bin/mv` will work.


Just try it out with a test folder or something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely no expert, however `rsync` would be a better choice IMO. Here's the MAN page: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html

A very basic implementation of what you are trying to accomplish would be my example below. Note the use of `--remove-source-files` so you can move then delete in the same command. Of course you can remove this to keep the source files.

`25 * * * * rsync --remove-source-files /var/www/website/current/integration/export/ /var/www/website/current/integration/export_completed/`

This would move everything *inside* the 'export' folder to the 'export_completed' folder. The asterisk is not needed. 
If you wanted to include the 'export' folder *and* it's contents, simply remove the trailing slash like so

`25 * * * * rsync --remove-source-files /var/www/website/current/integration/export /var/www/website/current/integration/export_completed/`

Read the man page for more options. Rsync is really powerful.

Comment: For clarity, when I say 'move' I mean it will first copy the files, then remove the originals. The end result is the same, but it's worth noting.

Comment: I would go with `rsync`, it is so powerful and rielable. but I have to admit that `mv` can do the job